# Python:TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing

Tags: python

Every time I run the following code, I get the error "TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing"

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
y = now.year

days_in_month_dict = {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31}

last_day = last_day + (days_in_month_dict[month2 - 1] - day2)
days = days - last_day
return days

print daysBetweenDates(1900,1,1,1999,12,31)
```

Full error message:

```
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7 /Users/a212440163/PycharmProjects/udas/numero.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/a212440163/PycharmProjects/udas/numero.py", line 57, in <module>
    print daysBetweenDates(1900,1,1,1999,12,31)
  File "/Users/a212440163/PycharmProjects/udas/numero.py", line 44, in daysBetweenDates
    last_day = last_day + (days_in_month_dict[month2 - 1] - day2)
TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing


    Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: As implemented, `days_in_month_dict` is actually a set, not a dictionary.  It would have the elements 28, 30, and 31 (not necessarily in that order).  To create a _dictionary_, you need to assign key-value pairs, e.g. `{1: 31, 2: 28, ..., 12: 31}` or `{'Jan': 31, 'Feb': 28, ..., 'Dec': 31}`.

Answer (score 2):

You have a set, not a dict, although their syntax and some semantics are similar.  A dict has keys and values, and you failed to supply the keys for yours.  Instead, add month numbers to turn this into a proper dict, and index by the month:

days_in_month_dict = {
    1: 31, 2: 28, 3: 31, 4: 30, 5: 31, 6: 30,
    7: 31, 8: 31, 9: 30, 10: 31, 11: 30, 12: 31}

last_day = last_day + (days_in_month_dict[month2] - day2)

Answer (score 0):

In your code `days_in_month_dict` is not a `dict`, but a `set` object.  Sets don't support indexing because they are unordered.

Try:

```
days_in_month = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

last_day = last_day + (days_in_month[month2 - 1] - day2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are trying to access an element of your set at a particular index (indexing). Sets, like dictionaries, do not support indexing.

days_in_month_dict[month2 - 1]

If you changed your set to a list:
[31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]

You’ll be able to access the elements by indexing

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access a set by using an index. A set does not support indexing. What you want is a list.

Use square brackets instead of curly braces.

```
a = [1, 2, 3] # This is a list
b = {1, 2, 3} # This is a set
print(a[0])
print(b[1])
```

output:

```
1
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                     
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>                                                                                   
TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing
```